# Getting a TypeError using the useRef hook..."null is not an object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, null, typeerror

Hello react developers.

So I'm putting together an app for a client. Client wants a page that plays a video (no sound, plays inline) when the video is in view in the viewport, and it pauses when the video is out of viewport. So I made a custom hook to do this. Here's my code (ignoring the imports, which are just useRef and useEffect):

```
const usePlayVideo = options => {
const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
const videoRef = useRef(null);
const handleVid = entries => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) videoRef.current.play();
    else videoRef.current.pause();
    };
useEffect(() => {
    const wrapper = wrapperRef.current;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleVid, options);
    if (wrapper) observer.observe(wrapper);
    return () => {
        if (wrapper) observer.unobserve(wrapper);
    };
    }, [wrapperRef, options]);
    return [wrapperRef, videoRef];
};
export { usePlayVideo };
```

Then, in the component, i import the hook and use it like so:

```
function ClientAsk() {
    const [wrapperRef, videoRef] = usePlayVideo({
        root: null,
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: 0.3,
    })

    return (
        {/* bunch of other divs and stuff */}
        <div className="grid_s_start_3 grid_s_span_20" ref={wrapperRef}>
            <video ref={videoRef} id="video" playsInline muted preload="auto" loop style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <source src={ClientVid} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
        {/* rest of other divs and stuff */}
        );
}

export default ClientAsk;
```

And that's that.

In browser on my dev environment, this works GREAT! Works as intended! I'm thrilled.

But I try it out on my iPhone, using iOS Safari, and it also works...UNTIL I return to the previous page while the video is playing.

So, there's a "< Back" link at the top of the page. When the video is not playing (i.e., I didn't scroll down far enough, or I scrolled past the video and it paused), the app goes back to the previous page, no problem!

BUT if I stop scrolling at the video, and it's playing, and I press the back button (or the Safari browser's back button), I am greeted with a dev error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'videoRef.current.pause')
handleVid
src/hooks/usePlayVideo.js:8
5 | const videoRef = useRef(null);
6 | const handleVid = entries => {
7 | const [entry] = entries;
> 8 | if (entry.isIntersecting) videoRef.current.play();
| ^ 9 | else videoRef.current.pause();
10 | };
```

Now, I THINK I know WHY this is happening...however, I simply cannot figure out how to fix this or make the error stop happening. I was wondering if anyone has any tips for this? Am I using the wrong hooks in my custom hook? Should I not use "null" as my default for useRef? Is this only an iOS issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing this line: `videoRef.current.play();` to `videoRef && videoRef.current.play();`  --- and also: else videoRef && videoRef.current.pause();

Comment: @SajibKhan I just tried that. Unfortunately it did not fix it. Same TypeError on mobile iOS Safari. (Works fine on Desktop.) Thank you for your response!

Comment: VideoRef is always truthy, its `current` value that can be falsy (null in this case), you can wrap your useEffect logic or handleVid logic with `if (videoRef.current) { }`

Comment: @Zac to clarify your comment, are you saying I should replace ```if (entry.isisIntersecting)``` with ```if (videoRef.current)```? or add videoRef.current to the current condition? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: it's not related to `entry.isisIntersecting` condition, the problem is that in this case your code is executed with `videoRef.current` = `null`, and in your current condition, you will either call `.play()` or `.pause()` and both will produce the same error, so you can wrap these three lines inside `handleVid` function in a condition  `if (videoRef.current) { }`

Comment: @Zac so I rewrote the handleVid function as 
```if (videoRef.current) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) videoRef.current.play();
        else videoRef.current.pause();
        };
    };``` 
and it seems to have addressed the problem! It no longer causes this error on iOS safari. Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: Apologies for how my code looks in the comment...I'm new to stackoverflow and comment formatting!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that this line of code returned a value of null that caused an error when returning to the previous page:

```
const handleVid = entries => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) videoRef.current.play();
    else videoRef.current.pause();
};
```

Per @Zac above, the reason for that is because the videoRef constant is always a true value as written, and its current value can be false (null in this case).

So, I rewrote it per his advice, as follows, wrapping the handleVid function in an `if (videoRef.current)` condition:

```
if (videoRef.current) { 
   if (entry.isIntersecting) videoRef.current.play(); 
 else videoRef.current.pause(); 
 };
```

This addresses the TypeError on Safari, and no longer shows up when returning to the previous page.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer. Thank you!